# How to find out which computer made the changes to a shared folder with delphi?

Tags: delphi

I am writing a program with Delphi that monitors a shared folder on my computer, where other people on the network have read-write access to it, I can log changes and info of changed files, but how can I find out which computer made the changes?

Is it possible to find the computer name or IP?

note: using [ReadDirectoryChangesW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365465%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Describe how you monitor changes

Comment: i use ReadDirectoryChangesW

Comment: It's probably not possible to know which computer modified the file

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/04/18/10412074.aspx

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, thank you for the link, the link leads me to Event Tracing for Windows (ETW API) after doing some searches on the net, This technique might come useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you poll files opened remotely on your pc and match them with monitored directory you might catch which computer opened the file. In order to not miss any short remote access to your files, hooking might be a better idea. An example utility that can show remotely opened files is psfile from pstools.